# Use SQL OUTPUT Clause Conditionally based on UPDATE result

Tags: sql-server, output-clause

I am curious if the OUTPUT clause can be used conditionally based on the UPDATE that creates the insert.

For example, with a boolean checkbox...

```
UPDATE myTable1 SET BinCheckBox = CASE WHEN BinCheckBox = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

OUTPUT

inserted.col1
inserted.col2

INTO

myTable2

WHERE myTable1.id = myFormField.id
```

...now, this part works fine. But I only want to use OUTPUT if the row in myTable1 is actually updated to myTable1.BinCheckBox = 1.

I had this working with a database Trigger, but I would like it all to happen in my statement if possible. Psuedo code like...

*UPDATE myTable 1 SET BinCheckBox = CASE WHEN BinCheckBox = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END...AND IF BinCheckBox updated to 1, then OUTPUT...*

Thank you for any advice

**UPDATE / ANSWER**

So instead of using `OUTPUT`, I am using `INSERT INTO myTable2 SELECT`, and a `DELETE myTable2 FROM` ... , to handle removing rows. Like so...

```
UPDATE myTable1 SET BinCheckBox = CASE WHEN BinCheckBox = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

INSERT INTO myTable2 (col1,col2)
SELECT col1,col2
FROM myTable1 m1
WHERE (BinCheckBox = 1)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT m2.id FROM myTable2 m2
WHERE (m2.id=m1.id));

DELETE m2 FROM myTable2
JOIN myTable1 m1 on m2.id=m1.id
WHERE m1.id=,y.id AND m1.BinCheckBox = 0;
```

This seems to work great.

Comment: No, you cannot. Any particular query will always generate a result set with a particular "shape" or no result set at all. What's wrong with including `BinCheckBox` in the `OUTPUT` and making the next stage (whatever it is) use a simple predicate on that column when consuming the result set?

Comment: Also, of course, in general `UPDATE`s are expected to apply as easily to *multiple* rows as to *single* rows. If your `UPDATE` affects a row with a mixture of `BinCheckBox` values, how would your proposed solution work?

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever ... this particular `UPDATE` is parameterized on a form. The statement runs on a button click, and a single ID is passed. This particular update will only happen on one row at a time.

Comment: Maybe so, but SQL Server wouldn't have that knowledge. You're only really allowed to write queries that (structurally) make as much sense for multiple rows as they do for single rows.

Comment: Ok. So with that in mind I am no longer using OUTPUT...but simple INSERT INTO SELECT. I will update my question to make it more clear...